# How to check if users google account has been added on device before starting GCM procedure?

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to check if user has added his google account on his device before starting the GCM registering procedure API 8?

When try to register without it the app gives a warning stopped unexpectedly when closing, so like to check first, alert the user and close the app.

Comment: `GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);` does not handle this scenario?

Comment: As far I know it only checks if the device supports GCM, not controlling the account...

Comment: Well, now, that stinks. Presumably there is a way via `AccountManager` to find out if there is a Google account, but I have not played with any of that yet.

Comment: Make sure that you catch the exception thrown by checkDevice(). It throws an exception if the device does not support GCM. So if the application crashes, the reason could be that you are not catching that exception.Are you catching it?

Comment: @Jagdeep Help me a bit, how to catch the exeption... I only use the statement like all tutorials. I think you mean by a if(...)? Thx.

Comment: I have added an answer about how to catch exception . No problem at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had a look at the source for checkDevice() and as far as I can see it only checks the API level and that the gcm package is on the device. So following on from CommonsWare's suggestion, this code appears to do the job for me:

```
private boolean deviceHasGoogleAccount(){
        AccountManager accMan = AccountManager.get(this);
        Account[] accArray = accMan.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        return accArray.length >= 1 ? true : false;
}
```

You will need the line

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

in the manifest

Comment: In API 23 and above you need to ask for permissions at runtime and not only specify it in the manifest

Comment: Seems starting from Oreo it became more complex https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAccountsByType(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 3):

You need to verify the response got from the GCM, if you get ACCOUNT_MISSING then you can handle the error.

In your `GCMIntentService Class` you have methods like `onRegistered() onUnregistered() onMessage() onError()`, In your `onError()` method

```
/**
 * Method called on Error
 * */
@Override
public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
    // HANDLE IF GCM SERVER SENT ERROR MESSAGES.!
}
```

[image]

For more information on error handling check the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)

Answer (score 0):

For your question about how to catch an exception:

```
try
{
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);
    System.out.println("Device has GCM capabilities. So registering for GCM");
   //// write code here to register for GCM
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Cannot cregister for GCM");
}
```

This is the logic for catching exception. So if any exception is throw in part after try, then the code in part after catch will be executed. checkDevice() throws an exception. If you wont catch the exception, the app will crash.

Also I dont think the syntax is all correct, but this code will give you idea about what to do.

Comment: No, this does not work. I get in LogCat "Device has GCM capabilities. So registering for GCM" but later comes "Registration error: ACCOUNT_MISSING".